# Form_for in Rails 3 is considering only the first submit button wth Form.serialize(this) in AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I'm working on a Rails 3 app. One of the view had only one submit button and now I'm supposed to add one more. I have done all the necessary changes in view file (.html.erb) and in controller.rb. But it considers only the first button (whichever it is) when either is clicked.

Why is it taking only the first button for consideration?? And how can I make both work??

**EDITED:**
I just checked the Railscast video
http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form?autoplay=true

It talks about multibutton forms n even mentions that some changes are to be done **if the form has AJAX request and form serialization**. My code has them!!

here's the code

[Added submit button calls the earlier button's function itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188455/added-submit-button-calls-the-earlier-buttons-function-itself)

Can anyone plsss help me make the necessary changes so that even with serialization both buttons are considered!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the name to the submit button in the view, like this:

```
= submit_tag 'Done', :class => 'btn', :name => "done"
= submit_tag 'Save', :class => 'btn', :name => "save"
```

And controller:

```
if params[:done]
  # do something done
elsif params[:save]
  # do something save
end
```

If you click the "done" button, the controller will work the "done".

And you want to lean more, you can watch the RailsCasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form?autoplay=true

Comment: Hi @JeskTop,
I have the same thing in my app, but it is taking only the first button in the view, whichever it is!!(Done button in ur case)...

Comment: I just checked the Railscast video It talks about multibutton forms n even mentions that some changes are to be done if the form has AJAX request and form serialization. My code has them!!

here's the code

Added submit button calls the earlier button's function itself

Can you plsss help me make the necessary changes so that even with serialization both buttons are considered!!